# How do I modify the PYTHONPATH for a single version?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.6, pythonpath

I'm trying to add this directory to my python2.7 path

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I can do so using:

```
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
```

or I can also add this line to my ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

However, this will add the same directory to my python2.6 path

```
import sys
from pprint import pprint as pp
pp(sys.path)
['',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/Users/Leo/Desktop/ReactiveFlows/Homework/HW1/HW1/Cantera',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python26.zip',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-darwin',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-tk',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-old',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this, described in [Modifying Python’s Search Path](https://docs.python.org/2/install/#modifying-python-s-search-path).

One way would be to add a `local.pth` file to `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` (or any directory already listed in Python2.7's `sys.path`), which contains the line

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```